# get data using regex

Tags: regex

hello
i want to get data from a site using  regex
http://helwa.maktoob.com/sec8180/art97048/pno1/title_%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%82-%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B4%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B1/index.htm

i used that regex `/<div class="txtblk"(.*)?<div class="imgv cls">/is`

but i gave me Invalid RegExp
why ?

i want to get data inside `<div class="txtblk"></div>`

Comment: Who is giving you that error message?

Comment: joomla component  called econtent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u may need to use a site that collects rss from links
like this
http://www.allwebdesignresources.com/webdesignblogs/graphics/turn-html-web-sites-into-rss-feeds-20-tools-converters-for-html-to-rss-conversions/

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your double-quotes.  Depending on your regex interpreter, those might be causing you problems.

Answer (score 1):

The regex itself looks valid.

It depends on where/how you are using it, though; JavaScript for example doesn't know the `/s` modifier. To simulate a dot-matches-all mode in JavaScript, use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Then, you might be running into problems with the quotes depending on the quoting rules for your language.

Also, you probably want to use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)?`. (Or, if it's JavaScript, `([\s\S]*?)`).

Finally, using regex to match HTML is not recommended. Use a DOM parser.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Joomla. But PHP should handle that regex fine - unless it's a quoting problem. Try Kyle Humfeld's suggestion of escaping the quotes.

Comment: but double-quotes is the code
please give me the modification

Comment: Try replacing each `"` by `\"` and see what happens.

Comment: no change.....can i write a regex to show all the data in the page to check if it read it correctly or not ??

Comment: Try `/.*/s`, and if that doesn't work, try `.*` (without the delimiters. Perhaps your component adds the delimiters by itself already).